# What does "pleasant rattle of a man" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, british-english, archaic-language

I've just watched Barry Lyndon. At the beginning Barry asked Nora if she was obliged to dance with another man and she responded: "*He dances prettily, to be sure, and is a pleasant rattle of a man*".

So what does "*pleasant rattle of a man*" mean? Maybe it's a pleasure to talk with him or he talks a lot that can't be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are right: 'rattle' is [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rattle) defined as

> an idle chatterer

All in all, Nora seems pleased with how entertaining this man's company is.